# Recovering ETH Sent to Wrong Network's Multisig Wallet

Tags: arbitrum, safe

I accidentally sent **ETH** from Arbitrum network to a multisig (multi-signature wallet) I created on the Ethereum main network.

How can I recover my assets knowing that this wallet doesn't exist on Arbitrum? Can anyone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 2):

First of all don't worry, and avoid making more transactions for now.

There might be a way to get your ETH back

In simple terms, you can try to create a similar wallet on the Arbitrum network using the exact steps you did on Ethereum mainnet.
So generate a multisig wallet with the same address you have on Ethereum.

This works **only** if you made the multisig wallet **yourself** using **your own private key**. If a service provider created the wallet, recovering the ETH would be much harder.

To do this, you need to find the "nonce" you used when creating the multisig wallet on Ethereum.

A nonce is like a counter that keeps track of how many transactions you've made. It's important not to make more transactions because it will change the nonce, making it harder or impossible to recover your ETH.

```
contract_address = keccak256(rlp.encode([creator_address, nonce]))
```

The idea is to generate the same multisig wallet address and then call the newly created multisig.

To summarize:

- Don't make more transactions.
- Try to create a similar wallet on the
  Arbitrum network.
- Find the nonce from when you created the multisig
  wallet on Ethereum main network.
- making more transactions can change the nonce and make recovery impossible.

Comment: How to find the nonce ? thanks!

Comment: You can find it by checking your latest transaction on arbiscan for example