# Sent ETH from exchange to arbitrum one network instead of ETH network

Tags: wallets, cpp-ethereum, recovery, arbitrum

Is it possible to retrieve the ETH by creating an exact same address on Arbitrum One network?

Is it the same steps as described here on this other similar question: [Recovering ETH Sent to Wrong Network's Multisig Wallet](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/147980/recovering-eth-sent-to-wrong-networks-multisig-wallet)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to recover my lost Ether by:

1. Creating a MetaMask wallet and selected the Arbitrum One network
2. Selecting "Import Account"
3. Pasted my ETH mainnet wallet private key in there
4. Same address was generated on Arbitrum One network and I have access to my lost funds.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are here talking about an address from a software wallet or a hardware wallet or any wallet you have the private key. If so you just have to switch network.

1. Import the account to the Metamask using the private key.
2. Visit [Chainlist](https://chainlist.org).
3. Search for Arbitrum One.
4. Click on connect wallet.

This will prompt to add Arbitrum One to your Metamask and you can approve it. Then it will be switched to Arbitrum One Network. Now you can see your ETH there.

The question you are referring is about a case where the wallet is a multi-sig wallet. Your case is not complex as it is.

Comment: correct, I have the private keys. I was able to recover it as I described in the response here. Thank you for your input :)